# Bind data to form on submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I have some form:

```
<form name="myForm" ... >
```

I'm selecting it like so:

```
 document.forms["myForm"]
```

On submit, I'd like to add several key value pairs to the form.  These key value pairs don't need to be in the form prior to a `submit()` function being called.  I'm adding the pairs like this:

```
document.forms["myForm"][key] = value;
```

However, this doesn't work.  It says I have an unexpected `[`.  What is the appropriate way to bind data to a form?

Example of key, value pair:

```
key = "PresentLevelsAssessment" + selected[i].id;
value = selected[i].getAttribute('data-type');
```

Comment: Is that your whole code? It looks all right.

Comment: @Scimonster Theres a little bit more to it but this is the spirit of it.  I'm definitely following the standards shown here.

Comment: What do you get if you use `document.forms["myForm"].elements[key].value = value;`?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the key and value pair being populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working so I just worked around it.  I was wanting to bind data based on whether or not some options were checked.  Instead of binding the data on submit I instead just write the html to the form whenever an option is checked.

```
$('.check').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        var html = '<div style="display:none" id="Info'+ $(this).attr('id') +'">' +
            '<input name="PresentLevelsAssessment'+ $(this).attr('id') +'" value="'+ $(this).attr('data-type') +'" />' +
            '<input name="PresentLevelsDate'+ $(this).attr('id') +'" value="'+ $(this).attr('data-date') +'" />' +
        '</div>';
        form.prepend(html);
    } else {
        $('#Info' + $(this).attr('id')).remove();
    };      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
document.forms.myForm.elements.key.value = ****anyvalue****;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. It's always best to explain the why and how in addition to providing functioning code.